# My edge collision algorithm is not working properly

Tags: java, algorithm, collision-detection

```
if(pl.y+pl.height >= a.y && pl.x+pl.width >= a.x+1 && pl.x <= a.x+a.width-1 && pl.y<=a.y) { //TOP
    colUP=true;
}
else  colUP=false;

if(pl.y <= a.y+a.height && pl.x+pl.width >= a.x+1 && pl.x <= a.x+a.width-1 && pl.y+pl.height>=a.y+a.height) { //BOTTOM
    colDOWN=true;
}
else colDOWN=false;

if(pl.x <= a.x+a.width && pl.x+pl.width>a.x+a.width && pl.y+pl.height >= a.y && pl.y <= a.y+a.height){ //RIGHT
    colRIGHT=true;
}
else colRIGHT=false;

if(pl.x+pl.width >= a.x && pl.x<a.x && pl.y+pl.height >= a.y && pl.y <= a.y+a.height){ //LEFT
    colLEFT=true;
}
else colLEFT=false;
```

I setup a debug that will tell me which of the 4 Booleans is being set to true, and they don't show that when I put the box 'pl' on top of box 'a' colUP is not equal to true, and they will only come true in weird instances where  box 'pl' is colliding with several box 'a's , and the collision for a certain side might be true when it isn't but if colUP is true then colRIGHT is true for some reason. (This code is inside a for loop that goes through an array list of Rectangles and sets the current Rectangle equal to the variable 'a' so that a.x is the box's x position)

Comment: Please describe what you want to happen. A visual would also be helpful.

Comment: each if statement checks to see if the one side of rectangle1 has passed the opposing side of rectangle 2. So It checks if the right side of rectangle1 is to the right of the left side of rectangle2, and the same for the rest of the sides. My main goal is to make this collision that will work with a Mario game that I am creating. So for blocks that only have collision on the top side, I can turn off the side collision of the bottom, left, and right sides.

Comment: So you do not want regular rectangular collision? You want to be able to test which sides the collision was on?

Comment: I suspect that the bug is outside the current code block. Could you provide more code, such as the loop where you are checking all the collisions?

Answer (score 1):

You have right logic but you set false for each condition separately. In reality all conditions should be true. So, use one boolean variable - isInRectangle=true; then check all conditions - left,right,top,bottom. If any is not true then isInRectangle=false;

It is simple AND logical operation for all 4 conditions.

Comment: This is assuming the goal is just to test true/false whether there is a collision or not. The goal of the question seems to be to detect separately for each rectangle edge, perhaps because different things need to be done depending on which edge(s) are collided with.